# Issues with getting file name & absolute path - Laravel 5 PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to automatically fetch some details of a file that has been uploaded, however there are two slight issues. I can't manage get the file name to show up without an extension, and the absolute path turns out wonky such as *C:\Users\Tyrx\Desktop\php part 2\FileDepository - back to\public/assets/7ofmMvm.jpg*.

Is there any chance somebody could guide me in the right direction? Here's the two snippets of code for generating the file name and file path.

File Name (for example, this results in 7ofmMvm.jpg instead of 7ofmMvm)

```
    $filelist->name = $this->request->file('asset')->getClientOriginalName();
```

File Path

```
    $fullfilepath = $destinationPath . $filelist->name;
    $filelist->file_path = $fullfilepath;
```

The full code of the function

```
public function store()
{
    $filelist = new Filelist($this->request->all());
    //store file details 
    $filelist->name = $this->request->file('asset')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filelist->file_type = $this->request->file('asset')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filelist->file_size = filesize($this->request->file('asset'));
    $filelist->uploader_name = Auth::user()->email;
    $filelist->save();
    // Save uploaded file
    if ($this->request->hasFile('asset') && $this->request->file('asset')->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/assets/';
        $fileName = $filelist->id . '.' . $this->request->file('asset')->guessClientExtension();
        $this->request->file('asset')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    }

    $fullfilepath = $destinationPath . $filelist->name;
    $filelist->file_path = $fullfilepath;
    $filelist->save();



    return redirect('filelists');
}

    if ($this->request->hasFile('asset') && $this->request->file('asset')->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/assets/';
        $fileName = $filelist->id . '.' . $this->request->file('asset')->guessClientExtension();
        $this->request->file('asset')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    }
    $fullfilepath = $destinationPath . $filelist->name;
    $filelist->file_path = $fullfilepath;
    $filelist->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From php manual

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
/www/htdocs/inc
lib.inc.php
php
lib.inc
```

and windows + php messes up paths with / and ...

There is this contribution from Legoas on the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

"The best way to get the absolute path of the folder of the currently parsed PHP script is:

```
<?php 

if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR=='/') 
    $absolute_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'; 
else 
    $absolute_path = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)).'/'; 

?>
```

This will result in an absolute unix-style path which works ok also on PHP5 under Windows, where mixing '\' and '/' may give troubles. 
"

Comment: I can't test this code at the moment, but would something like $filelist->name = pathinfo($this->request->file('asset'), PATHINFO_BASENAME  ); work for getting the file name without the extension?